# Google maps : Adding {draggable : true} to rendererOptions causes "TypeError: b.Zb is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, draggable

I built a very simple application that shows some routes and distances. 
[here](http://www.chambredhotecarcassonne.com/activites/)
It works fine ... but if I try to make the routes draggable i get an error :
"TypeError: b.Zb is undefined"   (not in my js files ... in GM's i guess.)

Here is the only lines I changed :

```
    var rendererOptions = {
      draggable: true,
      suppressMarkers: true
    };

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

I follow [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable?hl=fr)
... which is working fine.

So I guess I have done something wrong somewhere else. The problem is that this wrong thing I did doesn't cause any error without this option changed.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**The error is forced by this line(activMap.js, line 326):**

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
```

The documentation is a little bit incomplete , because as documented the argument passed to `setDirections` must  only  contain a `routes`-array(so this line should be correct)

But as it seems, internally, at least when the `draggable`-option is set, it also expects another property(which contains the argument that has been passed to `directionsService.route()` ) .

The name of this property (`Zb` in this case) isn't consistent, so it's not possible to pass this property reliable with the above line .

**Possible workaround:**

remove the line, and initially set in `calcRoute()` the `map`-property of  `directionsDisplay` to `null` (to hide a previously drawn route).

When the `route`-function was successfull set the `map`-property back to `map` after calling `directionsDisplay.setDirections()`

**Note:** you should clean up your code a little bit, you've included the maps-API twice and create a lot of useless instances of `DirectionsService` and `DirectionsRenderer`

Comment: Thank Dr.Molle for the quality of your answer and for the time spent. Moreover it solved my problem. Following your advise I tried to clean up my code by suppressing useless creation of instances.